# JSON Desrialization is making correct number of empty object

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am trying to deserialize **json**. It is being deserialized, that I know, because it is making equal number of array items as in the json string. But the items\objects of array are empty(null).

here is the json which is being returned.

```
[{
    "ID": "BM101",
    "courseName": "Mas Communications",
    "courseShortName": "MC",
    "isSynchronized": "0"
}, {
    "ID": "CS105",
    "courseName": "Discrete Mathematics",
    "courseShortName": "DM",
    "isSynchronized": "0"
}, {
    "ID": "CS65",
    "courseName": "Linera Algebra",
    "courseShortName": "LA",
    "isSynchronized": "0"
}, {
    "ID": "SE951",
    "courseName": "Digital Image Processing",
    "courseShortName": "DIP",
    "isSynchronized": "0"
}]
```

here is the class I made to deserialize it.

```
namespace ASAS
{    
    public class Serial_Courses
    {
        string ID {set;get;}
        string courseName {set;get;}
        string courseShortName{set;get;}
        string isSynchronized { set; get; }
    }
}
```

here is my code, I am using Newonsoft.JSON

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
Serial_Courses[] sc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Serial_Courses[]>(json);
```

Here is the debugged value of string `json` which I am recieving

`"[{\"ID\":\"BM101\",\"courseName\":\"Mas Communications\",\"courseShortName\":\"MC\",\"isSynchronized\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":\"CS105\",\"courseName\":\"Discrete Mathematics\",\"courseShortName\":\"DM\",\"isSynchronized\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":\"CS65\",\"courseName\":\"Linera Algebra\",\"courseShortName\":\"LA\",\"isSynchronized\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":\"SE951\",\"courseName\":\"Digital Image Processing\",\"courseShortName\":\"DIP\",\"isSynchronized\":\"0\"}]"`

when is being deserialized I'm getting array of four objects but the members are all null, take a look at the following screen-cap
[image]

**What could be the problem.**

p.s I am using PHP to create this json, here is my php code.

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type:application/json");
include('dblink.php');
$query = "";
if($_GET["mode"] == "1") 
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM courses";
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "2")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM grades";
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "3")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM students"; 
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "4")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM student_courses";
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "5")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM student_lecture";
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "6")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM teacher";
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "7")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM teacher_courses";
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "8")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM timetable";
elseif($_GET["mode"] == "9")
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM user_accounts";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$json_response = "";
if(  mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
{
    $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $json_response = json_encode($r);
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($result)>1)
{
    $firsttime = 0; 
    $json_response = "[";
    while( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
    {
        if($firsttime != 0)     
        {
            $json_response .= ",";          
        }

        $json_response .= json_encode($r);
        $firsttime = 1;
    }
    $json_response .= "]";
}
echo $json_response;
?>
```

Comment: bloody hell, such a blunder have I made... Thanks and please post it as reply so that I could accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newtonsoft can't access the properties of your `Serial_Courses` object and thus can't deserialize the JSON properties into them. When access modifiers aren't specified on the properties of a class, they are `private` [by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx). If you add `public` to your properties, the deserialization should work as expected.